# Ftp access denied to file after failed upload

Tags: ftp

I'm uploading file to ftp. Sometimes upload fails and on ftp chunk of a file leaves. e.g. 20 mb from file that have 50mb. Then I receive "550 Access is denied" when trying to re-upload file or delete that chunk of trash.

Could smb advice a solution?

Answer (score 1):

That means you have the right to upload files, but not to delete/replace them.
Contact ftp administrator to update your rights.

Update:
If you can delete other files, that means the incomplete file is probably still opened by your previous ftp session. The FTP server must have some timeouts for this, so you should be able to delete the file later when it is closed by the FTP server.

Comment: thank you for answer, but i can delete another files that were uploaded successfully